# Show an image (or icon) when a boolean value is TRUE with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, switch-statement, google-material-icons

So I have a list which have a column with boolean values in case some item have an attached file, when it does have an attachment it will show a "clip" icon. I want to do the same with an AngularJS table:

This is my code, HTML:
Notice there's a custom filter ("booleanFilter") in the **{{link.Attachments}}**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Attachments</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="link in links">
    <td>{{link.Attachments | booleanFilter}}</td>
    <td>{{link.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{link.Date | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Here's my SCRIPT of my filter:
I want to show an **Attachment Image** when there is an attachment (when it's true) and show nothing when it's false:

```
var myApp = angular
            .module('myApp', [])
            .filter('booleanFilter', function() {
              return function(booleanFilter) {
                switch(booleanFilter) {
                  case true:
                       return "clip.png";
                  case false:
                       return "";
                }
              }
            })
```

The bad thing with this code is that it shows "clip.png" as a string instead of showing the icon picture, also I tried putting a Material Icon's code:

```
<i class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
```

But it won't work... so any ideas or is there something I've been doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your flag is Attachments which can have true or false value then you don't even need filter:

```
  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="link in links">
    <td><i ng-if="link.Attachments" class="material-icons">attach_file</i></td>
    <td>{{link.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{link.Date | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I didn't know it was that easy

Comment: @Soul Eater, I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load local image with:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.attachImg = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('path/clip.png');
});
```

Then use [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) directive:

```
<img ng-src="{{attachImg}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make is simpler using  ng-if

```
 <tr ng-repeat="link in links">
<td>{{link.Attachments | booleanFilter}}</td>
<i  ng-if="(link.Attachments)>0" class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
<td>{{link.Name}}</td>
<td>{{link.Date | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</td>
```

So if "link.Attachment > 0" or in your case can be == true/false then show the icon, applying css class "material-icons" or your custom class